# Connect my WordPress site users to my public site account without showing my public site credentials

Tags: authentication, android

I have WordPress website and I want my site's users to connect any another public website's account using my public account's credentials without showing them to my credentials.

I explain more with an example. I have my WordPress website called abc.com and I have my personal account of any public website like xyz.com with my personal credentials like username and password. I want my websites users to direct (or any connect button in their account which used to) login to my xyz.com website's my account without showing my xyz.com credentials like username and password.

I got an answer from Manoj Vasshist as below...

*Approches :*

*you can directy put login link on of your xyz website to abc website or vice versa.*

*Use iframe to open you login are in another website.*

*3.Use authentication key with encryption on login page of abc web site and redirect with xyz website with auth key based on auth key you direct login on site.*

I have tried my level best but I didn't go through it.

But I am not that tech guy I am beginner. So, can anyone tell me how to do the same or step by step any link or video or web page or link or anything else method to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? I don't understand who's signing up for what. Are you asking how to let users sign into abc.com with their xyz.com account? Or are you asking how to let users of abc.com sign in to xyz.com using _your_ account? In other words you want to use your website to share your credentials to other websites? Do you own xyz.com? Or are you asking how to let users sign into Netflix, for example, using _your_ Netflix account?

Comment: Hi Jacob Peattie,

First of all thanks to attend my question. I will try to explain you again. I have (Administrator Role) my WordPress website abc.com which has so many users(Managers Role). Also I have an account of one public website xyz.com which username and password is with me.

I want my abc.com users (Managers Role) to give an access to my account area of one of public website xyz.com with my credentials. BUT Without showing my credentials to them-my users(Managers).

I hope I clear. If not let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Unless you control xyz.com this won’t be possible. You need to pass the credentials unencrypted to be able to log in.

Comment: I don't know who Manoj Vasshist is, but their suggestion only works if you control xyz.com.

Comment: Thanks Jacob Peattie, Sometime ago on YouTube I found something similar video to my problem not exactly. This video is I think from India. See the video between time 0:17 to 0:47. User of the portal login to main first portal with username and password than he search something and click on at 0:43 time at "click here" button and than he redirect to the another portal with same credentials of the first portal. I crossed check with as per my level best and found that after click here user redirect to different site which is not own by the first portal and all users are (See the second comment..)

Comment: login with the single credentials set up by the first site administrator. For example first site users account in second site (which came after click here button press) with username-abcd1234 and password is 1234567890 than all their users login to admin's account using admin's second site credentials but without knowing it. [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Kc-NiwlEVc and there is no control of second site's t of first site's admin.

Comment: That's a government website. They would have integrated with the third party websites. You can't do this for an arbitrary site you don't control.

Comment: Thank Jacob Peattie for your kind help and I really appreciated for your time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use curl method.
Here is a brief explaination:
So you have a form in your abc.com site (no need for iframe) then you should use $_POST method to send the data to a page you have created before and includes your curl php codes.
On the other server you should have created a page with your codes to receive the curl post and also after verifying user credentials send back the data (i recommend storing cookies for logged users so their credentials won't get leaked), also using the curl.

P.s. i would add this in the comments but unfortunately i don't have enough "reputations"

Comment: Hi mhdi, Thanks for your help. But I am not that much tech person so I am unable to to do the same. So, can you please give step by step solution or the same any web articles or video or similar things or any custom video of your recording to solve the same issue so I can do it easily. Also I have my own administrator privilege site in example abc.com but I do not have the same admin right in xyz.com public website. I have only normal user account on public site xyz.com. It's very useful to me if you have any video guide. Thanks in advance. Regards.